# share point portal customization

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

How can I customize share point portal and do it in a way that is easy to create and maintain. Below is a sample of the portal I inherited from someone else who was using images all over. I outlined in red each image. This image method introduces a lot of rigidity and loads of manual labor to make updates and changes.

can this be done using CSS or somethign other than images?

I tried using [this site](http://sharepointcanvas.com/spc/) but i think it falls short and only allows customization of basic share point objects.

As a bonus i would like to see if its possible for each portal in the group that represents a particular project pull project related details like "milestones" from a SQL driven project management system we had home grown. Our team has about 25 projects at any given time.

[image]

Comment: Your bonus question should be really be posted to a different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For [SharePoint Branding questions then Heather Solomon](http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/)'s blog is the first place to go to.

Especially have a look at the Resources on the right such as the [CSS reference](http://www.heathersolomon.com/content/sp07cssreference.htm)